# How can I sort and operate on unique key values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to iterate though an array of different ratings, sort by each unique id, sum and calculate the average of each id's ratings. Then save the averages in a new array, where I can call something like averageRating[i], where each entry will be each id's rating.

The original array of objects looks like this, where id could be any number.

```
data = [{id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 1, rating: 3}, {id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 1, rating: 4}, {id: 1, rating}, {id: 2, rating: 3}, {id: 3, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 5, {id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 2, rating: 4}, {id: 1, rating: 3}, {id: 1, rating: 2}]
```

I was able to do this work it out with only one particular id, doing something like as follows, but having some trouble working out how to do with a dynamic number of ids.

```
var [average, updateAverage] = useState(0);

let ratings = data.map((item) => item.rating);

// Calculate average of the array
let sum = ratings.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
let avg = sum / ratings.length || 0;
let avgRounded = Math.round(avg); // Round to nearest whole number

updateAverage = avgRounded;
```

Comment: Inside map function,you can use index and use that index as well . That's how all the data will be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably over the top concise but you can actually do it in one loop if you enjoy a bit of maths. See [this mathematical solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106313/regular-average-calculated-accumulatively)

```
const avgCount = {} // This is a temp var needed for accumulative averaging mathematical formula

// THIS VAR HAS THE ANSWER IN
const averages = data.reduce((averages, individualRating) => {
    // We need a counter of the number of times this ID has been seen already. This is needed by the algorithm.
    // Now we have seen a new rating with this id, increase the counter to reflect that.
    // If it's not there we start from 1.
    avgCount[individualRating.id] =  (avgCount[individualRating.id] ?? 0) + 1

    // Get the current rolling average. If there isn't one (this is first rating with this id we have seen), then its just the rating of this current item.
    const currAccumulatedAverage = averages[individualRating.id] ?? individualRating.rating

    // Calculate the new rolling average from the previous one
    averages[individualRating.id] = ((currAccumulatedAverage * (avgCount[individualRating.id] - 1)) + individualRating.rating) / avgCount[individualRating.id]
    
    return averages
}, {})
```

This *might* be highly performant as there are no multiple looping or intermediary structures. I say might because you also need to consider the complexity of the math operations and only benchmarking could prove it in real terms for modern JS engines. But it is at least a compact and satisfying solution that could also serve in streaming situations.

For this input:

```
let data = [{id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 1, rating: 3}, {id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 1, rating: 4}, {id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 2, rating: 3}, {id: 3, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 5}, {id: 1, rating: 1}, {id: 2, rating: 4}, {id: 1, rating: 3}, {id: 1, rating: 2}]
```

It returns

```
{1: 2.8181818181818183, 2: 3.5, 3: 5}
```

Comment: Oops made an error let me fix, give me some mins

Comment: All sorted now, messed up the algorithm originally :D

Comment: It's giving me {1: 11, 2: 2, 3: 1}

Comment: @Miller42 Sorry yes i updated, have you tried latest?

Comment: Yes, it looks good because no for loops but it's giving those values

Comment: Thats weird, can you paste your input array here?

Comment: Ah sorry I see what's happening. You dont want `avgCount `. This is not the final result, its a temp var used during calc since the algorithm has a mem requirement to store some temp counters.

Comment: Log the output of `data.reduce`

Comment: Have updated answer to make this more clear

Comment: Ah thank you very much, you are a genius. I do not understand the maths behind it but it works!!

Comment: Me neither! I just transliterated the accumulative average algorithm haha

Comment: Would you mind marking as accepted :)

Comment: No need to change but I just updated with an even cleaner version. Vanity reasons really -- its the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular loops and do all processing. Read inline comments:

```js
// Rating data
const data = [
  {id: 1, rating: 1},
  {id: 1, rating: 3},
  {id: 1, rating: 1},
  {id: 1, rating: 4},
  {id: 1, rating: 2},
  {id: 2, rating: 3},
  {id: 3, rating: 5},
  {id: 1, rating: 5},
  {id: 1, rating: 5},
  {id: 1, rating: 5},
  {id: 1, rating: 1},
  {id: 2, rating: 4},
  {id: 1, rating: 3},
  {id: 1, rating: 2}
];

// Create new object for id -> average ratings
const avr = {};

// Iterate data array
for(const item of data) {
  // Create object of arrays
  // for calculate avarage later
  if(avr[item.id]) avr[item.id].push(item.rating);
  else avr[item.id] = [item.rating];
}

// Iterate object and calculate average values
for(const el in avr) {
  // Reduce
  const sum = avr[el].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  // Calculate average and update object
  avr[el] = Math.round(sum / avr[el].length || 0);
}

// Test
console.log(avr);
```

Comment: Using ternary for side effects is so lame.

Comment: @RoboRobok ok, specially for you answer was updated)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great! However, I will avoid for loops if possible!